# 'list indices must be integers or slices, not str' когда беру значение из инпута

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, csv

У меня есть  файл в котором мне нужно расчитать среднее(предположим) значение определенного столбца. Когда я указываю индекс столбца все работает отлично:

```
import numpy as np
import csv
import os

os.chdir("C:/temp/test_data/")
readdata = csv.reader(open(all_171.csv, 'r'))
data = []
for row in readdata:
  data.append(row)

data.pop(0)

q1 = []

for i in range(len(data)):
  q1.append(float(data[i][8]))  #8 - my column num.
  

print('Mean of column 7 : %s'% (np.mean(q1)))
```

Если я хочу взять индекс столбца из инпута выдает ошибку:

```
q1.append(int(data[i][str(input('Select filter column: '))]))
```

Где я ошибаюсь?

Comment: `str(input('Select filter column: '))` возвращает строку даже если не оборачивать в `str`. Думаю в вашем случае нужно сделать `int(input('Select filter column: '))`

Comment: Спасибо, действительно возвращает стринг, с int все работает